# Having trouble with implementeing the Miller-Rabin compositeness in Python

Tags: python, math, cryptography

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post this question so if it isn't let me know! I'm trying to implement the Miller Rabin test in python. The test is to find the first composite number that is a witness to N, an odd number. My code works for numbers that are somewhat smaller in length but stops working when I enter a huge number. (The "challenge" wants to find the witness of N := 14779897919793955962530084256322859998604150108176966387469447864639173396414229372284183833167 in which my code returns that it is prime when it isn't) The first part of the test is to convert N into the form 2^k + q, where q is a prime number.
Is there some limit with python that doesn't allow huge numbers for this?
Here is my code for that portion of the test.

```
def convertN(n): #this turns n into 2^x * q
placeholder = False
list = []
#this will be x in the equation
count = 1
while placeholder == False:
    #x = result of division of 2^count
    x = (n / (2**count))
    #y tells if we can divide by 2 again or not
    y = x%2
    #if y != 0, it means that we cannot divide by 2, loop exits
    if y != 0:
        placeholder = True
        list.append(count) #x
        list.append(x)     #q
    else:
        count += 1
#makes list to return
#print(list)
return list
```

The code for the actual test:

```
def test(N):
#if even return false
if N == 2 | N%2 == 0:
    return "even"
#convert number to 2^k+q and put into said variables
n = N - 1
nArray = convertN(n)
k = nArray[0]
q = int(nArray[1])
#this is the upper limit a witness can be 
limit = int(math.floor(2 * (math.log(N))**2))

#Checks when 2^q*k = 1 mod N
for a in range(2,limit):
    modu = pow(a,q,N)
    for i in range(k):
        print(a,i,modu)
        if i==0:
            if modu == 1:
                break
        elif modu == -1:
            break
        elif i != 0:
            if modu == 1:
                #print(i)
                return a
        #instead of recalculating 2^q*k+1, can square old result and modN that.
        modu = pow(modu,2,N)
```

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: check out `sys.maxint`, I think in Python 3 int is unbounded... i.e should handle as large a value as there is memory available to store

Comment: Use the integer division operator `//` to do your division: `n // (2**count)` instead of `n / (2**count)`. The latter returns a floating-point result with precision limited to (typically) 53 bits.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't fix the issue. I think I'll try another algorithm with it

Answer (score 1):

I don't like unanswered questions so I decided to give a small update.
So as it turns out I was entering the wrong number from the start. Along with that my code should have tested not for when it equaled to 1 but if it equaled -1 from the 2nd part.
The fixed code for the checking

```
#Checks when 2^q*k = 1 mod N
for a in range(2,limit):
    modu = pow(a,q,N)
    witness = True #I couldn't think of a better way of doing this so I decided to go with a boolean value. So if any of values of -1 or 1 when i = 0 pop up, we know it's not a witness.
    for i in range(k):
        print(a,i,modu)
        if i==0:
            if modu == 1:
                witness = False
                break
        elif modu == -1:
            witness = False
            break
        #instead of recalculating 2^q*k+1, can square old result and modN that.
        modu = pow(modu,2,N)
    if(witness == True):
        return a
```

Comment: Thanks everyone who tried to help however, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Mei, i wrote a Miller Rabin Test in python, the Miller Rabin part is threaded so it's very fast, faster than sympy, for larger numbers:

```
import math

def strailing(N):
   return N>>lars_last_powers_of_two_trailing(N)

def lars_last_powers_of_two_trailing(N):
  """ This utilizes a bit trick to find the trailing zeros in a number
      Finding the trailing number of zeros is simply a lookup for most
      numbers and only in the case of 1 do you have to shift to find the
      number of zeros, so there is no need to bit shift in 7 of 8 cases.
      In those 7 cases, it's simply a lookup to find the amount of zeros.
  """
  p,y=1,2
  orign = N
  N = N&15
  if N == 1: 
     if ((orign -1) & (orign -2)) == 0: return orign.bit_length()-1
     while orign&y == 0:
       p+=1
       y<<=1
     return p
  if N in [3, 7, 11, 15]: return 1
  if N in [5, 13]: return 2
  if N == 9: return 3
  return 0
  
def primes_sieve2(limit):
    a = [True] * limit
    a[0] = a[1] = False

    for (i, isprime) in enumerate(a):
        if isprime:
            yield i
            for n in range(i*i, limit, i):
                a[n] = False
                
def llinear_diophantinex(a, b, divmodx=1, x=1, y=0, offset=0, withstats=False, pow_mod_p2=False): 
  """ For the case we use here, using a 
      llinear_diophantinex(num, 1<<num.bit_length()) returns the 
      same result as a 
      pow(num, 1<<num.bit_length()-1, 1<<num.bit_length()). This 
      is 100 to 1000x times faster so we use this instead of a pow. 
      The extra code is worth it for the time savings.
  """
  origa, origb = a, b 
  r=a  
  q = a//b 
  prevq=1  
  #k = powp2x(a)
  if a == 1:
    return 1
  if withstats == True: 
    print(f"a = {a}, b = {b}, q = {q}, r = {r}")   
  while r != 0:  
       prevr = r  
       a,r,b = b, b, r   
       q,r = divmod(a,b) 
       x, y = y, x - q * y 
       if withstats == True: 
         print(f"a = {a}, b = {b}, q = {q}, r = {r}, x = {x}, y = {y}")  
  y = 1 - origb*x // origa - 1
  if withstats == True: 
    print(f"x = {x}, y = {y}")  
  x,y=y,x 
  modx = (-abs(x)*divmodx)%origb 
  if withstats == True: 
    print(f"x = {x}, y = {y}, modx = {modx}") 
  if pow_mod_p2==False:   
    return (x*divmodx)%origb, y, modx, (origa)%origb
  else: 
    if x < 0: return (modx*divmodx)%origb 
    else: return (x*divmodx)%origb

def MillerRabin(arglist): 
  """ This is a standard MillerRabin Test, but refactored so it can be
      used with multi threading, so you can run a pool of MillerRabin 
      tests at the same time.
  """
  N = arglist[0]
  primetest = arglist[1]
  iterx = arglist[2]
  powx = arglist[3]
  withstats = arglist[4]
  primetest = pow(primetest, powx, N) 
  if withstats == True:
     print("first: ",primetest) 
  if primetest == 1 or primetest == N - 1: 
    return True 
  else: 
    for x in range(0, iterx-1): 
       primetest = pow(primetest, 2, N) 
       if withstats == True:
          print("else: ", primetest) 
       if primetest == N - 1: return True 
       if primetest == 1: return False 
  return False 

# For trial division, we setup this global variable to hold primes
# up to 1,000,000
SFACTORINT_PRIMES=list(primes_sieve2(100000))
  
  
# Uses MillerRabin in a unique algorithimically deterministic way and
# also uses multithreading so all MillerRabin Tests are performed at 
# the same time, speeding up the isprime test by a factor of 5 or more. 
# More k tests can be performed than 5, but in my testing i've found 
# that's all you need.
def sfactorint_isprime(N, kn=5, trialdivision=True, withstats=False):

    from multiprocessing import Pool

    if N == 2:
      return True
    if N % 2 == 0:
      return False
    if N < 2:
        return False
        
    # Trial Division Factoring
    if trialdivision == True:
      for xx in SFACTORINT_PRIMES:
        if N%xx == 0 and N != xx:
          return False
    
    iterx = lars_last_powers_of_two_trailing(N)
    """ This k test is a deterministic algorithmic test builder instead of
        using random numbers. The offset of k, from -2 to +2 produces pow 
        tests that fail or pass instead of having to use random numbers 
        and more iterations. All you need are those 5 numbers from k to
        get a primality answer. I've tested this against all numbers in 
        https://oeis.org/A001262/b001262.txt and all fail, plus other
        exhaustive testing comparing to other isprimes to confirm it's 
        accuracy.
    """
    k = llinear_diophantinex(N, 1<<N.bit_length(), pow_mod_p2=True) - 1
    t = N >> iterx
    tests = []
    
    if kn % 2 == 0: offset = 0
    else: offset = 1
    
    for ktest in range(-(kn//2), (kn//2)+offset):  
       tests.append(k+ktest)
    
    for primetest in range(len(tests)):
      if tests[primetest] >= N:
         tests[primetest] %= N
  
    arglist = []
    for primetest in range(len(tests)):
      if tests[primetest] >= 2:
        arglist.append([N, tests[primetest], iterx, t, withstats])
     
    with Pool(kn) as p:
       s=p.map(MillerRabin, arglist)    
    
    if s.count(True) == len(arglist): return True
    else: return False

sinn=14779897919793955962530084256322859998604150108176966387469447864639173396414229372284183833167

print(sfactorint_isprime(sinn))
```